# Simply switch output usage?

Tags: tensorflow

i got a game with only 10x2 pixels as input and it learns after one hour training doing it by itself. Now i want to use one float value output of the model instead of three classifier outputs. The three classifier outputs where stop,1-step right, 1-step-left.  Now i want to produce one output value which tells me e.g. -4 => 4 steps-left,  +2 => 2 steps-right and so on.

But after training for 1-2 hours, it only produces numbers around 0.001, but it should produce numbers between -10.0->+10.0 ?

Do i need todo it in a completly other way, or can i use an classifier model to output real value without changing much code ?

thanks for help

[game code link](https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_tensorflow_game/blob/master/pixel_hunter_game/10x2_real_output/10x2_real_output_pixel_hunter.py)

Answer (score 0):

Training a classifier is much simpler than coming up with a good loss function that will give you scalaer values that make sense. Much (!) simpler.

Make it a classifier with 21 classes (0=10 left, 1=9 left, 2=8 left,...,10=stay, 11=1 right, ..., 20=10 right)

Comment: thats not good, because i got 1024 speed values. And my goal is to have even more, so i need a real value output.  The loss function is the q-function from deepminds dqn. I think its generalized enough to be good for that task, or am i wrong?

Comment: sorry, the loss function is not the q-function. the loss function is target - readout_action.

Comment: Yeah, I am the wrong guy then. I gave up on good scalar-predictions. But curious to see whether someone else might reply who does have an idea.

Comment: By accident today I found that my experience is shared:
"When faced with a regression task, first consider if it is absolutely necessary. Instead, have a strong preference to discretizing your outputs to bins and perform classification over them whenever possible.)" (http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/ almost at the end of the text). Given you have so many speed values you might want to try a hierarchical classifier though, explained a bit above in the same text)

Comment: thanks, but the link is for "visual recognition", but i dont know if its "visual" when i only use sensor-values like degree and load ?  I put the values into a visual pattern, could be that this also applies to my try, but i still think, simple float values would be easier, but i didnt got it, till now :)

Comment: hi @friesel , i got some code which produces float output and still hunts the pixel. Not with the best reward, but i have only trained it for 2 hours (cpu only). I must play with the parameters, just thought your also interrested in experimenting with it :)    https://github.com/flobotics/flobotics_tensorflow_game/blob/master/pixel_hunter_game/10x2_real_output/10x2_real_output_pixel_hunter.py